# Rest Api oauth2 best way to limit users accessing other users data

Tags: rest, laravel-4, oauth

We have Rest Api created by Laravel 4 Php framework. We are using combination of scope and grant to prevent users accessing some resources. But we are having problem preventing one user accessing another user data.

**For Example**- in our application a user can log in using `email` and `password` and we use `password` grant type to create `access_token`.
 user can see their access token by using browser debugging tolls. Now, that user can use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or curl request with that access_token to get other users data. What is the best way to prevent user showing other user data ?

Answer (score 0):

When user login into the system, create access_token with roles and permissions return that access token to the user. When user calls the API with the `access_token`, then check that users is having the permissions to access the requested data.

If that user not having permissions then return with some error message.

You can create filters for this, In which you can check access_token permissions.

Userful like for Laravel routing- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing